# Wifi keeps disconnecting, NetworkManager reason -14

Tags: wireless, 20.04, network-manager

Until yesterday, my wifi has been running perfectly for as long as I've had this system (many months). Since yesterday, it has been dropping every 20-30 minutes, and reconnecting automatically after about 30 seconds (usually on 2nd attempt).

I've looked at the many existing "wifi keeps disconnecting" questions on this site but none of them has solved my issue.

I've got a desktop with a wifi USB dongle, with very strong signal.

Taking advice from answers to similar questions, I've already disabled power management on wifi and USB, but the issue persists.

When the wifi drops, the command `sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager` shows the following line:

```
NetworkManager[...]: <warn>  [161...] sup-iface[0x...,wlx...]: connection disconnected (reason -14)
```

Is there a list of Network Manager reason codes from which I can see what -14 means?

Comment: Qucik google search gave me this. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingNetworkManager/ReasonCodes

Comment: Do you have a VPN?

Comment: Yes, I use OpenVPN for connecting to work. But I've had these disconnections even when not using the VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

14 NM_DEVICE_STATE_REASON_PPP_FAILED PPP failed

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingNetworkManager/ReasonCodes

From the link above.

Comment: Thanks. I see 14 means PPP failed (and I'm not sure if 14 is the same as the -14 given in the log, or if the negated number is totally different). But that doesn't make sense: PPP failed implies a problem between my router and the ISP. But when my Ubuntu PC disconnects, my other PCs (one Fedora laptop, one Windows laptop, and two Android phones) continue to be connected.

Comment: I am sure the - does not make a difference.  You may want to inquire of your ISP if there is a known issue.